# Do exist any ways to avoid handling events on empty space like border radius?

Tags: react-native

[image]

I attached screenshot, there you can see arrow on circle View component where I was clicking. Problem is that onPress event is calling when I press there. Do exist any ways to avoid handling events on these places, just circle should handle events, probably we should in some way disable disable that handling or use some additional tools which can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-native-svg helped me to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pan Responder to detect the x,y coordinate where the click is happening and calculate if the touch where within the circle. Will be pretty straight forward. [Read more here.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder)

Comment: Yes, it can be the solution for this simple example, but what if I will have more complex shape, or image, it can looks like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZgGX.png

Comment: What do you think, can be possible to draw shape with a RN library, and have events only for filled area?